# Android Studio: How to add an item from listview1 to listview2 onClick

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview

Very new to Android Studio and trying to solve the following; I have 2 list views and would like to 'onClick' add an item from listView1 to listView2.

The item clicked (and added) must be stored from ArrayList1 --> ArrayList2.

How would I do this?

Screenshot of layout.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKwvm.jpg

I've tried following youtube tutorials to resolve this but they do not seem to cover my issue explicitly.

```
public class SearchFilter extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";

    private ArrayAdapter adapter1;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter2;
    private ListView listView1;
    private ListView listView2;

    private String names1[] = new String[] {"mitch", "luke", "samantha", "jessi", "janelle", "jordan", "rick"};
    private String [] names2 = new String[names1.length];

    private List name1List = new ArrayList();
    private List name2List = new ArrayList();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_filter);

        for(String a : names1){
            name1List.add(a);
        }
        for (String b : names2){
            name2List.add(b);
        }



        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        adapter1 =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name1List);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name2List);
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                name2List.add(name1List.get(position));
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                (SearchFilter.this).adapter1.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2019-10-16 06:16:38.843 29135-29191/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 06:48:39.276 29135-29191/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 07:52:39.608 29135-29191/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 10:00:39.972 29135-29191/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 10:00:41.539 536-536/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/.fcm.BugleFirebaseInstanceIDService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7000ddf u0a54 RCVR idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
2019-10-16 12:12:47.116 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 12:13:17.318 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: QUOTA_EXCEEDED
2019-10-16 12:14:17.534 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 12:16:17.706 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 12:20:36.753 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 12:28:44.679 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
2019-10-16 12:45:19.843 3132-3205/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
```

Comment: Use Interface for item click and in place of listview use Recyclerview for best performance..

Comment: Your code seems fine. The error is related to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I could amend the firebase issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not enough to refresh the ListView data, setAdapter() must be called before to load the information correctly. Do as follows :-

```
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```